# Manipulating data to create a vector in R

Tags: r, vector

I'm trying to manipulate data into a form that allows me to create vectors easily, however I'm running into a bit of an issue.

I have data that copies into R like so:

[image]

For the sake of simplicity I'll just use the first ten numbers, such that I have something like the following:

```
1
4
1
7
1
1
3
4
5
2
```

I would like to create a vector including each of these numbers like so:

```
greatVector <- c(1, 4, 1, 7, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2)
```

Yet I'm only able to do so by manually entering in each comma and hitting backspace to properly position the next number.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try `scan`

```
scan('file.txt',  what=numeric(), quiet=TRUE)
#[1] 1 4 1 7 1 1 3 4 5 2
```

Answer (score 4):

@akrun mentioned `scan` for file input, but it can also be used to enter data directly from the console. Type this at the console and copy the data as separated by carriage returns or spaces:

```
 vec <- scan()
1: 1      # the numbers by the side are only printed upon data entry
2: 4
3: 1
4: 7
5: 1
6: 1
7: 3
8: 4
9: 5
10: 2
11:     # an empty line terminates data entry
Read 10 items
> vec
 [1] 1 4 1 7 1 1 3 4 5 2
```

It's also possible to enter character values if the `what` argument is set to `""` or `character(0)`

```
vec_a <- scan(what="")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try copying and pasting the text displayed in R console into a `read.table`instruction like so :

```
greatVector<-unlist(read.table(text="1
4
1
7
1
1
3
4
5
2",header=F,sep="\n"))

> greatVector
 V11  V12  V13  V14  V15  V16  V17  V18  V19 V110 
   1    4    1    7    1    1    3    4    5    2
```

As mention by @akrun, you can also use `scan` instruction, also copying and pasting the text :

```
greatVector<-scan(text="1
4
1
7
1
1
3
4
5
2",what=numeric(),sep="\n")

> greatVector
 [1] 1 4 1 7 1 1 3 4 5 2
```

Comment: It doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: @Pascal, then I must have misunderstood the question because I thought the OP wanted to put in a vector a list of numbers that were displayed in the console after some operation

Comment: @ChuckD. does my proposition answer your question in a way or another ? If not, meaning that I indeed misunderstood your request, I will delete it